# como se retorna un JSON si tengo que agregar el contentType y processData? AJAX, JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

Es que intento enviar archivos desde Ajax, jquery. Pero para esto debo de tener el processData y el contentType en (false), pero esto me causa un problema a la hora de retornar el valor en JSON

```js
$('#id_form').submit(function(e){
      
            
        var FormData = new FormData($('#id_form')[0]);
        
        $.ajax({
            data: FormData,
            url: 'prueba/enviar/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json', //Quiero que me retorne en JSON, pero aunque agrege el dataType, no me functiona 
            contentType: false,//Estos dos campos se usan para el envío de archivos
            processData: false,//Estos dos campos se usan para el envío de archivos
            success: function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta); //Lo que me retorna es un texto
            }
             
        })
        
        
    
        e.preventDefault();
    })
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código que recibe los datos en el servidor y envía la respuesta, desde allí debes mandar un JSON. Si te manda texto es porque mandas texto desde el servidor.

Comment: Si añades el accepts: "application/json"